# JSON stringify call in ajax, that is compatible with ie 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I wanted to use jQuery's `$.each()` and it works, but not in IE6. So enter json2. So I am getting the data and binding it to a var using

```
var theData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Then calling through an array

```
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<theData.Event.Football.length; i++)
    {
        alert(theData.Event.Football[i].time);
    }
```

Although it's just saying "Cannot read property 'Football' of undefined"

Here is the JSON, after 6 hours of trying variations, i am use im just misunderstanding something simple.

```
{
"Event":{
    "Football":[
        {
          "title": "Some Event",
          "time": "6:00" ,
          "competitors": {
            "competitors1": "Boaty Mc Boat",
            "competitors2": "Disco Dave"
          },
          "win": {
            "win1": 1.3,
            "win2": 1.89,
            "win3": 1.79
          }
        }, {
          "title": "Some Event",
          "time": "7:00" ,
          "competitors": {
            "competitors1": "Flesh Wound",
            "competitors2": "None Shall Pass"
          },
          "win": {
            "win1": 2.03,
            "win2": 1.79,
            "win3": 1.79
         }
     ]
  }
}
```

Final Fix, there was a problem with the AJAX syntax, here is the working version that allows the above code to work

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "football1.json",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: true,
    contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
        alert('working');
       // do stuff
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.debug(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: *"I wanted to use Jquery's $.each() and it works, but not in i.e 6. So enter json2."* Um...they have nothing to do with one another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
var theData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

takes a data structure and turns it into a string (JSON).

If `data` is *already* not a string, just use it directly.

If `data` is a *string* and you want to go the other way, you want

```
var theData = JSON.parse(data);
```

...where, again, `data` is a string containing JSON.

At which point, either `$.each` or your `for` loop (or your [various other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript), modulo IE6 (!) support) will loop through `theData.Event.Football`.

Comment: Hey T.J Thank you for clearing it up. It works calling it directly, i should have mentioned the JSON data is called through an AJAX request and the loop is called in the .success() , however this doesn't work in IE 6,7 need to spin up another VM to test 8, but im guessing same story.

Comment: So Long story short, i looked up some old versions AJAX requests, turns out it was just the syntax wasn't working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :D

Answer (score 1):

If you stringify the data, it will be a string. You cannot access the object's properties in a JSON-stringified representation of the object.

Your `for` loop looks fine and should work with IE6, but it should be executed on `data`, not `theData`.

Or is `data` also a string? Did you mean to use `theData = JSON.parse(data)`?